# Module Error Even though all the modules are installed in a VENV

Tags: python, python-venv, python-poetry

I am using a python virtual environment inside Windows, all the modules are installed. For example the module "environ" is already installed successfully using poetry and manually using pip and an attempt to install it manually results to "the requirement already satisfied". However, when importing the module, I get an error "Module environ" not found.

I have installed some of the modules that I need to use, such as environ, dj_database_url, ... etc manually and it shows in the list when I run pip list as shown below

```
Package              Version
-------------------- --------
asgiref              3.7.2
build                1.1.1
CacheControl         0.14.0
certifi              2024.2.2
charset-normalizer   3.3.2
cleo                 2.1.0
colorama             0.4.6
crashtest            0.4.1
distlib              0.3.8
dj-database-url      2.1.0
Django               5.0.3
dulwich              0.21.7
environ              1.0
fastjsonschema       2.19.1
filelock             3.13.1
idna                 3.6
importlib-metadata   7.0.1
installer            0.7.0
jaraco.classes       3.3.1
keyring              24.3.1
more-itertools       10.2.0
msgpack              1.0.8
packaging            23.2
pexpect              4.9.0
pip                  24.0
pkginfo              1.10.0
platformdirs         4.2.0
poetry               1.8.2
poetry-core          1.9.0
poetry-plugin-export 1.6.0
ptyprocess           0.7.0
pyproject_hooks      1.0.0
pywin32-ctypes       0.2.2
rapidfuzz            3.6.1
requests             2.31.0
requests-toolbelt    1.0.0
setuptools           65.5.0
shellingham          1.5.4
sqlparse             0.4.4
tomlkit              0.12.4
trove-classifiers    2024.3.3
typing_extensions    4.10.0
tzdata               2024.1
urllib3              2.2.1
virtualenv           20.25.1
zipp                 3.17.0
```

Whoever, I still get the module error. This is happening with some other modules too. And yes I have activated the venv and used both manual and poetry to install them.

Comment: What command are you using to activate the environment, and install packages? The fact that poetry appears in the list above implies it's not the activated venv, poetry needs to be installed in the system python (or pipx etc) since it creates the venv that it installed packaged into so it has to be installed somewhere else.

Comment: (to activate a venv installed by poetry use `poetry shell`)

Comment: I am activating it using the Venv\Script\activate...I get your point about the poetry `env` . However, I have also manually installed them using pip. Shouldn't they be available inside the venv environment?

Comment: They should, provided you activated the correct env before installing using pip. If you don't have `in-project = true` set in your `poetry.,toml` then poetry will create a named env somewhere on your system (not in the project folder). So maybe you have a venv folder in your project but it's not the one poetry is managing?

Comment: I would delete the local folder, and run `poetry install` then `poetry shell` and see if that works